# django:ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, django, sockets

I am new to the programming and i have been trying to develop an audio player using jQuery/HTML5.The audio source to the jquery is being passed by AJAX response.The audio play is fine in my local host while using Laptop.But if i connect my smartphone and try to play the audio, i get the "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error.

Can someone provide me a solution?.
Thanks in Advance

Exception details:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)

File "C:\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 593, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

### [18/Jul/2017 18:04:21] "GET /images/mpthreetest.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59

Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.35', 33876)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)

File "C:\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 593, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()

File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 95, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\socketserver.py", line 628, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)

File "C:\Python35\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)

File "C:\Python35\lib\socketserver.py", line 684, in **init**
    self.handle()

File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()

File "C:\Python35\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent

### AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'